# Custom post type not showing wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-type

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Post Types', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Post Type', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

I've added a custom post type like this, [image]

As you can see, the posts are not showing but they are counted, and if I access the link to a post it just says it does not exist and I can't acces it anymore, on the edit page I can preview it, but after I save it it just goes away.

Comment: You have a WPML Plugin installed? Is a new post type or old?

Comment: It's new and I don't have wpml

Comment: Plugin installed in wp?

Comment: Yes, it's added in a plugin with just this, not in functions.php

Comment: yes i answer at your question... Not call post_type but posttype `register_post_type ('posttype', $args);`

Comment: First time i tried register_post_type ('templates', $args); and it did not work, so probably posttype will be the same

Comment: impossible, with `post_type` it does not work for me, but` posttype` or `templates` yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a post_type called post_type. Try removing the underscore ("_"):

From:

```
register_post_type ('post_type', $args);
```

To:

```
register_post_type ('posttype', $args);
```

And it will work! (you will have to change the url of the current page)